ios: Can you pull two video streams from back cameras using multicam session?
Can I pull two separate video streams from 2+ back cameras using multicam session
in AVFoundation (or any other iOS api)?
The plan is to glue them side by side into a single frame
UPD after watching 2019 WWDC session on duocam a better question is:
where is the AVDuoCam sample app the presenter refers to after PiP app can be located?
UPD2 filed FB14286390 request in bugreporter.apple to publish AVDualCam conspicuously missing from https://github.com/cash0211/WWDC-Sample-Code-2014...2019/tree/master/wwdc2019

I imagine you'd want to start here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/249/ ... then here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avcam_building_a_camera_app ... and finally here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avmulticampip_capturing_from_multiple_cameras

Right, I wonder where AVDualCam in https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/249/?time=1984 is stashed. It's not here https://github.com/cash0211/WWDC-Sample-Code-2014...2019/tree/master/wwdc2019

Based on various comments, Apple only keeps WWDC sample code available for 3 years. You might want to take a look at this: https://github.com/Neos21/multi-cam ... a quick look at the code appears to indicate support for multiple back camera input.

the sample code to that wwdc2019 is available, the issue is that AVDualCam is not (and probably never was) listed. I've filed a ticket on bugreporter for Apple to consider adding it. Probably they had a bet how many years will pass before anyone notices that conspicuous absence. From what I can dwell on the presenter in the video that character is like a spy full of doublebottoms.

Feel free to post as a standalone answer: the Neo code from Japans works. At least on iPhone "pro"
